# Shuffling Pandas Dataframe Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to shuffle dataframe columns. Currently I do it this way:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy

df = pd.DataFrame(numpy.random.rand(1,5))
print (df)
df_as_list = df.values.tolist()[0]
random.shuffle(df_as_list)
df_shuffled = pd.DataFrame(df_as_list).transpose()
print (df_shuffled)
```

Before:

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.472918  0.261734  0.987053  0.921826  0.144114
```

After:

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.472918  0.921826  0.987053  0.144114  0.261734
```

So it does the job, but there must be a better way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**try**:

```
def shuffle(df, n=1):
    for _ in range(n):
        df.apply(np.random.shuffle)
        return df
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(10), 'B':range(10)})

shuffle(df)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

A little different way:

```
cols = list(df.columns.values)
random.shuffle(cols)
df.columns = cols
```